# синхронизация трех датафреймов по времени

Tags: r

Есть три датафрейма немного разной длинны потому что наблюдения велись начиная с разного времени,

как их можно синхронизировать по времени чтоб оставить только те наблюдения которые есть во всех трех фреймах и выкинуть те которые попадаются только в отдельных фреймах

вот сами дата фреймы

```
> head(sec1)
        date  time   open   high    low  close vol
1 2016.09.06 08:45 3081.5 3082.5 3080.5 3080.5   6
2 2016.09.06 08:50 3081.5 3081.5 3079.5 3080.5   6
3 2016.09.06 08:55 3081.5 3082.5 3081.5 3082.5  19
4 2016.09.06 09:00 3083.5 3083.5 3081.5 3082.5  19
5 2016.09.06 09:05 3083.5 3085.5 3082.5 3085.5   8
6 2016.09.06 09:10 3086.5 3086.5 3084.5 3086.5  15
> head(sec2)
        date  time  open  high   low close vol
1 2016.09.13 13:00 95.34 95.40 95.33 95.39  36
2 2016.09.13 13:05 95.40 95.43 95.39 95.41  40
3 2016.09.13 13:10 95.42 95.44 95.40 95.42  37
4 2016.09.13 13:15 95.41 95.42 95.39 95.39  25
5 2016.09.13 13:20 95.40 95.41 95.38 95.38  21
6 2016.09.13 13:25 95.39 95.42 95.38 95.42  32
> head(sec3)
        date  time    open    high     low   close vol
1 2016.09.14 18:10 1.12433 1.12456 1.12431 1.12450 137
2 2016.09.14 18:15 1.12444 1.12459 1.12424 1.12455 139
3 2016.09.14 18:20 1.12454 1.12477 1.12446 1.12469 148
4 2016.09.14 18:25 1.12468 1.12474 1.12442 1.12453 120
5 2016.09.14 18:30 1.12452 1.12483 1.12442 1.12482 156
6 2016.09.14 18:35 1.12481 1.12499 1.12472 1.12474 126
```

Те на выходе должно получиться три датафрейма одинаковой длинны (nrow) и все строчки датафреймов должны иметь одинаковую дату и время

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то нужно определить пересекающиеся интервалы дат и времени и отфильтровать наблюдения, попадающие в эти интервалы.  Омечу, что приведённые в качестве примера данные не пересекаются по датам.

Определим границы для дат:

```
min_date <- list(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
    sapply(. %>% .subset2("date") %>% as.Date(format = "%Y.%m.%d") %>% min()) %>% 
    max()
max_date <- list(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
    sapply(. %>% .subset2("date") %>% as.Date(format = "%Y.%m.%d") %>% max()) %>% 
    min()
```

Теперь то же самое для времени:

```
min_time <- list(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
    sapply(. %>% .subset2("time") %>% as.POSIXct(format = "%H:%M") %>% min()) %>% 
    max()
max_time <- list(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
    sapply(. %>% .subset2("time") %>% as.POSIXct(format = "%H:%M") %>% min()) %>% 
    min()
```

Теперь можно отфильтровать наблюдения:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% 
    mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%Y.%m.%d")) %>% 
    filter(date >= min_date & date <= max_date) %>%
    mutate(time = as.POSIXct(time, format = "%H:%M")) %>% 
    filter(time >= min_time & time <= max_time)
```

Чтобы код работал, нужно загрузить пакет `dplyr`.

Comment: Спасибо!  Но что то не понятно что мы получили на выходе ...  Код запускается без ошибок но  когда я пробую открыть  df1 после работы кода то получаю """""> df1
[1] date  time  open  high  low   close vol  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)"""""""  рис. http://prntscr.com/cm43sn

Comment: Таблицы из вашего примера не пересекаются по времени и датам, поэтому на выходе вы получаете пустые таблицы.

Comment: Да нет, пересекаються, перепроверил только что еще раз, а в моей иллюстрации вверху просто указаны всего лишь шапки - head(), самих данных больше 2000 строк в каждой df

Comment: `&&` надо `&` заменить. Исправил ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Насколько я понимаю, задача сводится к тому, чтобы оставить в каждом датасете только те наблюдения, для которых есть наблюдения с аналогичными значениями `date` и `time` в двух других датасетах.

---

Мне видится самым простым решением такое:

- слить вместе все три датасета
- сгруппировать наблюдения по переменным `date` и `time`
- посчитать количество наблюдений в группах
- оставить только те сочетания `date` и `time`, которые встречаются 3 раза
- отфильтровать исходные датасеты по датасету пересекающихся наблюдений

  ---

**Код** (не проверял - лень генерировать исходные датасеты; напишите, если где-то что-то упустил, и не работает)

```
library(tidyverse)

df_cross <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3) %>%
        group_by(date,time) %>%
        summarise(occurance = n()) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        filter(occurance == 3) %>%
        select(-occurance)

df1_refined <- left_join(df_cross, df1, by = c('date', 'time'))
```

---

## UPD все оказалось еще проще

```
df_cross <- intersect(df1 %>% select(date,time), 
                  df2 %>% select(date,time), 
                  df3 %>% select(date,time))

df1_refined <- left_join(df_cross, df1, by = c('date', 'time'))
```